# Strange behavior of layer panel / legend in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, symbology, legend, user-interface, panel

I've been noticing a strange behavior in the layer panel / legend of QGIS 3 - I don't know exactly when I noticed it, but it must have been since QGIS 3.

The legend entries in the layer panel are expanding or shrinking after open and closing the layer properties or closing the group in the panel. It seems to happen only with SVG-Symbol entries. In some cases, just the symbols getting smaller or bigger.

It happened in QGIS 3.10, 3.14, 3.16, 3.18, 3.22.
All my symbol units are in Meter.

[image]

I have also a short screen recording to this behavior:
http://www.map-site.de/tmp/strange_legend_behavior_qgis322.mp4